# Nominate Users in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am building a portal which handles registrations in a different way.

Step 1 : It requires users to nominate other users based on their email id.
Step 2 : Then the admin approves the user email id ( and probably give in the user name there itself )
**strong text**
Step 3 : An email is sent to the user that the new id has been created and only then the user can login.

Is there a way to accomplish this task ? I read the user module forums but couldn't get the required information.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps 2 and 3 are built-in features of Drupal i.e. admin users can create user accounts and notify them about their newly created accounts. For step 1 you may consider the Webform module (http://drupal.org/project/webform). Create a webform for authenticated users where they can put email addresses and submit.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help I really would like to do that. I've been using webform in the portal for a different purpose too. I will try the same and will post if there are any issues.